# Does Oracle auto-compress the table as it grows large?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, compression, sql-drop

I have a table in my database.Earlier while performing the `DROP` DDL there was no issue. But after some days as the table become large and i tried `DROP` DDL it is saying:

> SQL Error: ORA-39726: unsupported add/drop column operation on
>   compressed tables.

As per my DBA no commands were run to compress the table.

Comment: So what is your question? Why this happens or how to solve it?

Comment: It depends on the type of compression. For a table compressed for **direct- path inserts**, you cannot drop the column. However, if the table is compressed **for all operations**, then you can use `SET UNUSED/ DROP UNUSED`

Comment: @GolezTrol I know how to solve this my question was why it happens

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> As per my DBA no commands were run to compress the table.

You could check the compression status by querying **[DBA|ALL|USER]_TABLES** view.

For example,

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE t(col1 NUMBER, col2 NUMBER) COMPRESS;

Table created.

SQL> SELECT table_name, compression,compress_for
  2  FROM user_tables
  3  WHERE table_name ='T';

TABLE_NAME COMPRESS COMPRESS_FOR
---------- -------- ----------------------------
T          ENABLED  BASIC
```

Dropping the column depends on the type of compression. For a table compressed for **direct- path inserts**, you cannot drop the column. However, if the table is compressed **for all operations**, then you can use `SET UNUSED/ DROP UNUSED`.

**How to drop the column in a compressed table**

The only way is:

- **decompress** the entire table
- Make the column **unused**
- Then **drop unused columns**.

```
SQL> ALTER TABLE t SET UNUSED COLUMN ename;

Table altered.

SQL> ALTER TABLE t MOVE NOCOMPRESS PARALLEL 4;

Table altered.

SQL> ALTER TABLE t DROP UNUSED COLUMNS;

Table altered.

SQL> SELECT table_name, compression,compress_for
  2  FROM user_tables
  3  WHERE table_name ='T';

TABLE_NAME COMPRESS COMPRESS_FOR
---------- -------- ----------------------------
T          DISABLED
```

Comment: So you mean to say while creating the table if we give compress then only the compression of the table is done otherwise not.

Comment: @JManish Yes. At least you can check the status as I have shown.